# How to define a group object given an object $a$ in a finitely complete category $C$

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Let $C$ be a finitely complete category and $a\in C$. Since $C$ is finitely complete, there exists (i.e. pullback) unique morphisms $m,n:a\times a\rightarrow a$ such that $m\circ1_a=n\circ 1_a$: i.e. $m=n$. We can take this $m$ to be our "multiplication". There is also a unique morphism $e:a\rightarrow1$ where $1$ is our terminal object; this can serve as our "multiplicative identity". How can I derive an $i:a\rightarrow a$ so that $(a,m,i,e)$ forms a group object in $C$?

I have used the fact that $C$ allows pullbacks to derive $m$. On the other hand, I have used the fact that $C$ possesses a terminal object to find $e$. What property gives me $i$?

Comment: The multiplicative identity should be a morphism $1\rightarrow a$, not the other way around. Thinking of $\mathsf{Set}$ the multiplicative identity is an *element* of $A$ ie a morphism $* \rightarrow a$. It is **not** the unique constant map on $a$!

Comment: @PrudiiArca You're right.. But that would require an initial object, right? I thought group objects could be defined in finitely complete categories only?

Comment: The following is a **very** informal argument: If in a complete category every objection carries a canonical group structure, this structure should morally be the *free* (or arguably *cofree*) group structure on that object. In particular the construction of a free group would be much easier (or the forgetful functor $\mathsf{Grp} \rightarrow \mathsf{Set}$ should have a right adjoint). Neither of this is the case, which leads me to think that there is no construction of a canonical group structure on an arbitrary object in a complete category...

Comment: not really. In $\mathsf{Set}$ the terminal object $*$ and the initial object $\emptyset$ are distinct, nevertheless a group object (aka group) is defined with a unit element being a morphism $*\rightarrow a$...

Comment: @PrudiiArca Ok.--If we had an initial object, $e$ would then be defined. Any idea on how we can get $i$ in that case?

Comment: @Falq: initial objects are not relevant here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in the comments, you've messed up the direction of the unit; it's a map $e : 1 \to a$, and such a map need not exist in a finitely complete category. An easy example is to take the category of $G$-sets for $G$ a nontrivial group; there a map $1 \to X$ for a $G$-set $X$ corresponds to a fixed point, so we can take for example $X = G$ being acted on by left multiplication, which has no fixed points and hence no possible unit map.

In most categories with finite products (this is all you need to define group objects, and actually with a little fiddling you don't even need this), most objects don't have a group object structure; it's a quite special feature of $\text{Set}$ that (assuming the axiom of choice) every set has a group structure. For example, in $\text{Top}$ a group object is a topological group and the underlying topological space is heavily constrained, e.g. it must be homogeneous, its fundamental group must be abelian, etc.